# conditional `ctypedef` with Cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I need access to the `uint64_t` typedef from `stdint.h` in some wrapper code that I'm writing and I can't figure out how to get it done. The problem is that from what I can tell from the docs, my `ctypedef` will have to take the form:

```
ctypedef unsigned long uint64_t
```

or

```
ctypedef unsigned long long uint64_t
```

depending on if `WORDSIZE` from `bits/wordsize.h` is 64 or 32. I haven't been able to find out out how to get access to this preprocessor definition from Cython and if I could, Cython doesn't seem to like `ctypedef` statements in `if` statements and when I try to put an `if` statement in a `cdef` block, it seems to confuse it with a declaration. Any ideas? Hopefully I'm just missing something really basic here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cdef extern from "stdint.h":
    ctypedef unsigned long long uint64_t
```

Any `ctypedef` that's `extern`'d won't have a typedef generated in the .c file. Cython will include `stdint.h` and your C compiler will use the actual typedef from there.

The only thing that the type provided matters for is when cython generates code that automatically converts between C types and Python types. Using `unsigned long long` means that Cython will use `PyLong_FromUnsignedLongLong` and `PyLong_AsLongLongAndOverflow`. This way, you hopefully won't get any truncation on conversion.

Comment: perfect. That's exactly what I was using in the meantime. I don't have to change anything. It probably should have occurred to me to check the generated C file now that I think about it.

Answer (score 10):

Cython includes these definitions in the module [`libc.stdint`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/ffb5aa5d94fef005a65cc6762c622c674e670468/Cython/Includes/libc/stdint.pxd) already:

```
from libc cimport stdint

ctypedef stdint.uint64_t foo
```